# FormatException for inserting date into database

Tags: c#

I get the formatException whenever I try to insert a date in the database.

I converted a date into a string and attempted to insert into a database. I have tried all means but it is caught as an exception. Find the code below:

```
$ DateTime date =  Convert.ToDateTime(rows["Limit_maturity_date"].ToString());
string newdate = date.ToShortDateString();//.Replace("/","");
DateTime dd = DateTime.ParseExact(newdate, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
queryString = "INSERT INTO Table (CODE, NUM, CCODE, LCODE, SACCODE, LIM, L_DATE)" +
                    " VALUES ('" + int.Parse(rows["code"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["number"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["Ccode"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["Lcode"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["Sacode"].ToString()) + "','" + int.Parse(rows["limit"].ToString()) + "','" + newdate "')";
```

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, you're approaching the problem of inserting data into the database incorrectly.

You're converting everything into strings, and including those strings in the SQL. **Don't do that.** Use parameterized SQL instead, and just put the values directly into the parameters, with no conversions to strings first. This solves three problems:

- [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Mixing code (SQL) and data (parameter values)
- Problematic string conversions

It looks like you've got a *lot* of string conversions going on, and I suspect there's no need for *any* of them. Any time you're tempted to convert a value to a string, ask yourself whether you really have to. Any time you write code which converts a value to a string and then to another type, like this:

```
int.Parse(rows["code"].ToString())
```

... you should be *really* suspicious. What's the execution-time type of `rows["code"]`? Could you just use a cast instead?

Comment: The exception i am having is really about the "newdate" i am trying to insert into the database. the databse is an oracle database. i was only given a table name and the column fo that table. It is complaining about the date

Comment: @mayowaogundele: Yes, you shouldn't be doing any string manipulation here at all, basically. You haven't even said which line you're getting the exception on - my guess is that it'll be the first line, which means the problem isn't even on insert... but fundamentally you should work on removing *all* of these string conversions if you possibly can. Every single one is a point of potential failure.

Comment: Ok. Let me give you a brief: The int.Parse(rows["code"].ToString()). 'rows'is of type Datarow. 'code' is the name of the column retrieved from the database, and the execution value is an integer.

Comment: thanks. i got it. The issue was that i tried to pass one of the rows which as double to an int

Comment: @mayowaogundele: Right - so if you'd just used a cast, you'd have found the *exact* problem much sooner. Hopefully you're now able to remove *all* of the string conversions.